# Creating a simple custom tag to show or hide body

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

Im trying to create my own custom tag so i can display or hide the content between the tag depending on an attribute set.

```
<mytag:isUserInRole role="admin">Show admin specific text</mytag:isUserInRole>`
```

Basicly i want to show the text between the tags if the logged in user has `role==admin`.
I thought it would be easy, but so far i've had no luck. If i in my tld-file set `<body-content>empty</body-content>` I get this exception:

"According to TLD, tag auth:isUserInRole must be empty, but is not"

If i set `<body-content />` i get this one:

Unable to compile class for JSP - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1857)

Can anyone see what im doing wrong?

Her is my tld-files relevant tag:

```
    <tag>
    <name>isUserInRole</name>
    <tag-class>no.mycompany.tag.AuthorizationTag</tag-class>
    <body-content />
    <attribute>
        <name>role</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

And here is my AuthorizationTag doStartTag-method:

```
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException{
    System.out.println("Role"+role);

    //Check that role is given and securitycontext is not null
    if(role==null|| SecurityContextHolder.getContext()==null || SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null){
        return Tag.SKIP_BODY;
    }
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if(hasPermission(auth)){
        return Tag.EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
    } else {
        return Tag.SKIP_BODY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `<bodycontent>jsp</bodycontent>`, also note the difference between `<body-content>` and `<bodycontent>`

Answer (score 1):

As I know there is a `taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"` which does exactly you are trying to achieve - it has `<authorize>` tag. If you don't want use it, you could investigate the source code, e.g. [org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.webflow/spring-faces/2.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/faces/security/FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler.java).

Comment: Note that Facelets are different from JSP so the tag handler might not be quite the same.

Comment: Yeah i was investigation that one, but i could not find any documentation on how to use it to my needs, so i decided to just implement my own solution...